# Can’t access my Mac’s SSH port outside of my home network. Forwarding rule is set. What might be wrong?

Tags: networking, ssh, port-forwarding

As the title said, I am trying to set my mac as a ssh server. My mac's local IP is `192.168.0.21` and my external IP (router IP) is `98.202.108.***`. I went to the sharing and enabled the Remote Login. Also I tried to forward the local 22 port to external via my router. My router is a [Motorola MG7315](https://motorolanetwork.com/mg7315.html).

Here is a screenshot of my router’s forwarding rules:

[image: Screenshot of my router’s forwarding rules.]

However. In the internal network, I can

```
ssh [usrname]@192.168.0.21
```

or

```
ssh [usrname]@98.202.108.xxx
```

But on the external network, I can ping `98.202.108.xxx` but can't SSH to it. I asked Xfinity, they said my 22 port is not blocked. I closed all firewall, nothing happens. I tried the [port forward tester](https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/), still I can't see the 22 port from the external IP.

I used nmap to scan my external IP (from port 1 to 100), it says `All 100 scanned ports on c-98-202-108-xxx.hsd1.ut.comcast.net (98.202.108.xxx) are filtered.`

Is this a problem of the router or something else I can do to get this working?

Comment: Purely as a suggestion, if possible, you likely should use a port other than 22 (perhaps 23 or 24). While anecdotal, I personally have run into this exact same issue with Comcast Xfinity and have seen a number of similar questions here with no good solutions. They do not not officially block port 22 but it certainly seems that there is a general problem running SSH (or anything else) on that port for many.